# Pass variable from command line to mongo command

Tags: c#, mongodb, batch-file

I have a script which does:

```
mongo localhost:27017/MyDB --eval "db = connect("localhost:27017/SomeDB")"
mongo localhost:27017/MyDB --eval "db.copyDatabase(var1frombatch, var2frombatch)"
PAUSE
```

in which var1frombatch & var2frombatch are passed to this batch from c#.net code as %1, %2, my question is how can i use the variable in my --eval doe ?

I tried

```
mongo localhost:27017/MyDB --eval "db = connect("localhost:27017/SomeDB")"
mongo localhost:27017/MyDB --eval "db.copyDatabase('%1', '%2')"
PAUSE
```

but did not work

Comment: What does the parser execute? (run it with `echo on` to see)

Comment: nothing it cannot read %1 and %2 as batch variables

Comment: so your question isn't "how can I use the variable in the batchfile" but "how do I pass a variable to the batchfile". Sadly I can't help you with c#.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, but that's not what i mean, i already have the variable passed into this batch script of mine.  They are %1 and %2, now i want to use them in the --eval section as database names, but i cannot parse them

Comment: Why don't you solve this with PowerShell?

Comment: eh... how do i do that ? I'm sorry i'm noob in terms of shell scripting

Comment: does a simple `echo %1, %2` parse them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has an feature to run shell scripts on the command line.
In your case, one javascript for multiple operations works better than evaluate multiple mongodb functions.

Run a script like:

```
%MONGODBDIR%mongo localhost:27017/SMSManagement --eval "var dbA = '%1', dbB = '%2'" %SCRIPTSDIR%\shellscript.js
```

And in your shellscript.js

```
print("Copying database from " + "database:" + dbA + " to " + "database:" + dbB);

var result = db.copyDatabase(dbA, dbB)
printjson(result);
```

The result will output like:

```
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

More information about this you can read here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Comment: hello thanks for your reply, your code did not work, the program cannot recognize %1 and %2 inside --eval

Comment: You told that %1 and %2 are the arguments? Place the script in a bat file and call batch.bat "DB_A" "DB_B"' and %1 and %2 should works like it supposed to.

Comment: Yeah, i tied and its working now, thanks a lot man, it was very helpful !